# Oracle jdk in Ubuntu

Tags: java, openjdk, oracle

I removed openjdk-7 completely using `apt-get purge` and installed oracle jdk(8u45).I have the oracle jdk in path and it is working well .The Problem is that, if I try to install any software(from cmdline or software center) which depends on java([open]jdk) ,I am forced to install openjdk. Is there any work around for this...?
Os   : Ubuntu 15.10

I appended this in /etc/profile :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME 
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Comment: You can try to hold it with `sudo apt-mark hold openjdk-7-jre`...

Comment: If I want to install package XXX(which depends on java) , can I do something like this `sudo apt-get install XXX && sudo apt-mark hold openjdk-7-jre`

Comment: No, you must first do that apt-mark command, but I don't know 100% if it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the default version of Java to be used by Ubuntu using this:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

It will give you a choice if there are multiple versions installed or will set up properly if it finds just one version.

Comment: Thanks....but, i have already done this....didnot work

Answer (score 0):

I am answering from the RPM perspective, but I'm sure DEB has something similar in place.

Every package has Provides and Requires, they do not have to match the name of the package. So for example OpenJDK provides java and java-devel. And every package that Requires it will grab it as well.

The problem is that there is no other providers for java and java-devel, Oracle JDK cannot be redistributed by license, rarely anyone cares packaging IBM or Azul JDK, other JVM implementations are not feature-full enough.

So the only workaround for your issue is:
1. establish the alternatives as suggested by aramboi.
2. create a synthetic package that will not have anything inside but will Provide java and/or java-devel.

That will be the trick to make dpkg think you have everything needed in place and it will not download openjdk any more. About 8 years ago that could cause the problems with software linked to libjvm.so, but I doubt there's anything left that still links to libjvm.so instead of just running the java executables.

Answer (score 0):

I think better approach is to use additional repository [ppa:webupd8team/java](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) for installing Oracle JDK 7,8,9.

Details you can read here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html.

Comment: Even if i use PPA , `openjdk-7-jre` in dependancies list of softwares will not be satisfied..

Comment: As I see when I have installed java using `ppa:webupd8team/java` it will not install `openjdk-7-jre` in case if package depends on java, for example I removed package [maven](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/maven) and this package depends on  `openjdk-7-jre, openjdk-8-jre`, but after installing package `maven` again additional package `openjdk-7-jre` was not installed, I also verified and I didn't have it installed previously. So usage of repository `ppa:webupd8team/java` should solve your problem.